# Angular v15+ accessing server-side rendered JSON/JS Object in .NET Core MVC Razor page (.cshtml)

Tags: javascript, angular, .net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I am trying to access a json object rendered by a .NET Core MVC Razor page in an Angular v15+ SPA.

The root code I have is as follows:

```
@page
@model Some.ServerSide.Model

@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Angular SPA";
    Layout = "";
}

<script id="extension__config">
    let json = JSON.parse(@Model.SomeServerSideObject.RenderedAtRuntime); /* the object to be referenced in Angular */
</script>

<app-root></app-root>

<!-- Runtime -->
<script type="module">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ng/_runtime.cshtml") /* partial view containing Angular runtime js*/
</script>

<!-- Polyfills -->
<script type="module">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ng/_polyfills.cshtml") /* partial view containing transpiled polyfills js */
</script>

<!-- Main -->
<script type="module" >
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ng/_main.cshtml") /* partial view containing transpiled main js */
</script>
```

nb: I should point out that I'm transpiling the Angular app on ng build and using Node to double-escape @ characters so Razor plays nicely when calling the MVC partial views. So far so good, I have an MVC server-side that runs a simple Angular hello world! SPA when the @page is run.

However, I've tried a couple of methods to consume the extension__config json object:

- The first involved creating an @Injectable Window service/provider which returned the expected window object (so I could access window.location.hostname for instance), but drilling down into window.document.scripts.namedItem("extension__config").text would throw compile-time TypeScript null/undefined errors (TS2345) that I couldn't seem to remove with Optional Chaining or if-else conditions.
- The second method was an @Injectable service/provider that would reference a static JSON file when running the app via ng serve, and call a Razor handler (IActionResult OnGet) when debugging via VS2022 or in production. This method works as expected via ng serve but throws syntax errors that only seem to occur when the Angular app is transpiled.

I've also looked at Microsoft's suggested ways of working with Angular and .NET Core MVC which seem convoluted and don't quite fit with my use case.

I feel like Angular ultimately transpiles down to JS, which works within .cshtml pages, so this should be fairly simple - but I'm clearly missing something - any advice or assistance would be much appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, as suspected, deceptively simple:

```
.cshtml:
<script id="some-id">@Html.Raw(Model.SomeServerSideObject.RenderedAtRuntime)</script>
```

```
Angular Service:
JSON.parse(window?.document?.scripts?.namedItem('some-id')!.text);
```

The ! null assertion in the Optional Chaining resolved the null/undefined issue.

I'm sure this isn't best practice, but it works!